# How to set the default sorting order for this AngularJS website?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sorting

I am using AngularJS. I would like to make a table to sort by the first column immediately after the webpage finish loading. The HTML table code looks like this;

```
<table class="table table-hover data-table sort display">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col_1">
              <a href="" ng-click="columnToOrder='col_1';reverse=!reverse">Column 1</a>
            </th>
            <th class="col_2">
              <a href="" ng-click="columnToOrder='col_2';reverse=!reverse">Column 2</a>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredList | orderBy:columnToOrder:reverse">
            <td>{{item.col_1}}</td>
            <td>{{item.col_2}}</td>     
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Now, the table simply loads the data without any particular sorting order as the webpage loads until I click on the column heading. If I want to set the default to be sorted by column 1 immediately after the webpage loads, how should the html code look like? Or do I have to modify the controller instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you can initialize the value of `columnToOrder` like this:

```
$scope.columnToOrder = 'col_1';
```

Comment: Wow! I have verified that to be the correct answer! Will accept your answer after 10 minutes.

Comment: One more question. Suppose I want to sort col_1 in reverse order by default. How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Then you can also default that value... `$scope.reverse=true;` or `$scope.reverse=false;`